# Validationerror when field is empty

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14, validationerror

I have created a Validation Error to show up when the submit button is clicked and the condition of the field is empty. But when I try to test it when the field is filled, the validation error still showing up. What's wrong with my code ?

```
def action_approved(self):
    for rec in self:
        expense_account = self.env['account.pettycash.voucher.wizard.line'].search([('expense_account','=',False)])
        if expense_account :
            raise ValidationError('Fill the expense account!')
        else :
            rec.state = 'approved'
```

I expect validation error to show up when field is empty and approve when filled

Comment: If one `account.pettycash.voucher.wizard.line` record has `expense_account` set to `False`, Odoo will show the validation error. You need to make the validation error depend on the current record processed by the `action_approved` function

Comment: @Kenly expense_account is many to many field object from another class. Should i use api.depends on it ?

Comment: How is the expense_account field related to the current model?

Comment: `depends` decorator will not fix that issue

Comment: @Kenly you're right, i already tried tried add decorator but still same. Perhaps do you have suggestion ? expense_account is many2one from account.pettycash.voucher.wizard.line class with relation from account.account

Comment: Where did you declare `action_approved` function and why you are checking `expense_account`?

Comment: i declare action_approved on account.pettycash.voucher.wizard class. because my task is create warning when expense account from account.pettycash.voucher.wizard.line class record is empty

Comment: Use the relation between the wizard and lines to check the expense account

Comment: @Kenly is this the relation ?
voucher_line = fields.One2many('account.pettycash.voucher.wizard.line', 'line_id', string='Voucher Line')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if one expense account in voucher lines is not set and raise a validation error, loop over `voucher_line` field and check if `expense_account` is not set (`if not line.expense_account` then raise the validation error.

***Example:***

```
def action_approved(self):
    for rec in self:
        for line in rec.voucher_line:
            if not line.expense_account:
                raise ValidationError('Fill the expense account!')
        rec.state = 'approved'
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess, you are checking the whole table. How is the class `account.pettycash.voucher.wizard.line` related to current `self` ? You need to include that as well in search condition.

```
expense_account = self.env['account.pettycash.voucher.wizard.line'].search([
('expense_account','=',False),
('relational_field', '=', self.id) #Need this condition as well.
])
```

Comment: expense_account = self.env['account.pettycash.voucher.wizard.line'].search([
('expense_account','=',False),
('account.account', '=', self.id) ]), like this ? i tried and not working :(